# Batch file status needed to run another .bat file

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have a some requirement to kick off a batch script by checking if the earlier .bat script is still running or completed. Is there anyway to find the process form the tasklist as it lists only the .exe files and other applications but not .bat file. Could someone please help me on this with any other feasible options, if any.

Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Thankyou, Saikiran

Answer (score 0):

```
wmic process where commandline='C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c ""C:\\Users\\David Candy\\Desktop\\test.bat" "' get commandline
```

Use `find` to parse.

Use `wmic process get commandline` to list your batchfile's command line.